# How to sum a column based on the passed column name dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I have the following sample data.

```
ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: '06703851', weight: 10, billamount: 200, },
  { position: '06703852', weight: 20, billamount: 300, },
  { position: '06703853', weight: 30, billamount: 400, },
  { position: '06703854', weight: 40, billamount: 500, }
];
```

I get a column name dynamically and I need to perform the sum of that column. For instance, if the `weight` column is passed, I should sum the `weight` column and return the sum. I tried the following code and it's giving an error at `t => selectedColumn`. Please help!!

```
caltotal(selectedColumn: string) {
  this.total = this.ELEMENT_DATA.map(t => selectedColumn).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your class/interface has to modify to support with [index signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures).

```js
class PeriodicElement {
  position!: string;
  weight!: Number;
  billamount!: Number;
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

2. Access the property value with the index signature.

   2.1. For the scenario with property is not a `Number` type, you may check its type first and for my use case I default the value as 0 for property which is not a `Number` type.

```js
caltotal(selectedColumn: string) {
  this.total = this.ELEMENT_DATA.map(t => t[selectedColumn])
    .reduce((acc, value) => acc + (typeof value === 'number' ? value : 0), 0);
}
```

[Demo @ TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAogMlCyUByAVA+gEQIIqwLggAUQAnASwHsATMgYylAFsQA7MAbQF0IBeCdgFAQIAbwgAHCgGcyYSiwIByAAwA2AOzKAzAA4ArAEZFAGggB3EGQDmACzAEDy0wCMywYAENGFAK5sCAEzKThAAvsZCohLSsvJKapq6egEm5pa29hBBLm6e3n6ZWsGm4ZFikjJyFAoQKhra+lqpFtZ2BEU57l6+-hAALMVhEcLlMVU1dYn6fc3pbf0hrl35vXqDoQKcANwCArSeUlJEpJQ09EyskCKRFbHVAIQEUmDkLFY7wi0ZjxBIPozOUgfCBLPI9MA-P4AoGRdgAaxAAE8ni8yG9OAQPCxETsNgJQJAwBQwB5gLwIModgIAGZ+WjjCC0UlEknAAAUUhAoHpICoAGEKMB-jVnq8rABKUSRFmk8mwBDIdDYXAAOkYHnEbMgPAAfBAOJzuWBeQKhYwWJxxZFhCqSLyfLQQGy2R5aLRTAA3Uk+ECS3UQV20CAAaggWsR4hAFGpEC9QpAvB4fEULH+gJIiggAH5Y96EwRlOLTIXcbsmcAZezFF87IpxTtaNUpIKQCrgBQrGyAEQoYmymuZLumSv1svMvtV0HdAp1vZNlttjvd3uskG5ae9If6if1oA)